# Issue with a select query (Pyodbc)

Tags: python, sql, ssms, pyodbc

I am using Pyodbc to access a Microsoft SQL Server database. I have the following query being built in code:

```
SELECT created, transactionID, balanceEffect
FROM dbo.table
WHERE (SELECT YEAR(created) = 2020) 
  AND (SELECT MONTH(created) = 11) 
  AND (SELECT DAY(created) = 17) 
  AND balanceEffect > 0 
  AND TransactionTypeID = '1321837129837129213' 
ORDER BY created
```

Where `created` is a `DATE` column.

When it gets to executing the query I see the following error:

> ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near '='. (102) (SQLExecDirectW); [42000] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near '='. (102); [42000] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near '='. (102)")

It seems like there is a problem with the subquery stuff. I haven't been able to find a similar issue online, and I believe this code (or a very similar piece of code) was working previously in this project. Does anyone have any idea what might be causing it?

Comment: You don't need the subqueries. Just `WHERE YEAR(created) == 2020 AND ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `SELECT`s are not correct.  You just want:

```
WHERE YEAR(created) = 2020 AND 
      MONTH(created) = 11
      DAY(created) = 17 AND
      balanceEffect > 0 AND
      TransactionTypeID = '1321837129837129213'
```

Or more simply:

```
WHERE CAST(created as DATE) = '2020-11-17' AND
      balanceEffect > 0 AND
      TransactionTypeID = '1321837129837129213'
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. This is what I needed, much appreciated. Don't know why I thought I needed to select, fresh pair of eyes saved the day cheers

Answer (score 0):

The subqueries make no sense, and are not needed. Just check `created` against literal dates, like this:

```
SELECT created, transactionID, balanceEffect
FROM dbo.table
WHERE 
    created >= '20201107' and created < '20201108'
    AND balanceEffect > 0 
    AND TransactionTypeID = '1321837129837129213' 
ORDER BY created
```

You might want to simplify the date filtering conditions as:

```
CONVERT(date, created) = '20201107'
```

However this is less efficient: the whole `created` column needs to be converted to a date before it can be filtered; this cannot take advantage of an index. This is why I recommend the half-open interval filtering, as shown in the first query.

Of course, if `created` has no time component, then you would just do:

```
created = '20201107'
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply very helpful info. Oversights by me